# Google scripts JDBC aurora connection error

Tags: google-apps-script, amazon-aurora

I have a script getting data from an Aurora Mysql database every 30 minutes using this line:

`const conn = Jdbc.getConnection(DBHOST + DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);`

It has been successfully running for 12 months. As far as I can tell, nothing has changed but it has been intermittently failing over the last couple of days but is now failing every time.

The error is:

> Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.

*May 10, 2021, 11:22:40 AM* First failure

*May 10, 2021, 11:54:30 AM* Successful

*May 10, 2021, 12:22:40 PM* Failed again

...

*May 11, 2021, 7:24:30 AM* Most recent successful run, and it has been consistently failing ever since.

No changes have been made to any AWS security groups and it's not an IP restriction issue.

I've tried using the IP address instead of hostname - did not work (and I understand this isn't recommended for Aurora anyway). Credentials are correct and work from SequelPro locally.

My best guess, based on the intermittent-now-consistent behaviour, is that Google are rolling out an update to servers and it took some time to propagate.

Comment: This issue could be related to [Problems with V8 runtime and JDBC
](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149413841). It seems that the issue is being worked on, so that could mean changes are being made.

Have you checked if changing from `V8` to `DEPRECATED_ES5` does make it work?

Comment: Thanks - I forgot to mention I toggled V8 on/off and got the same error. I think I experienced connection issues 9+ months ago in this project so switched V8 off back then to resolve it. Looks like the V8 migration might be catching up with me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. I just have to say that I, too, have experienced the exact same symptoms.

On May 10, jdbc connections in google apps script became intermittent. Some were successful, some were not. I cannot determine any criteria to distinguish why.

As of May 11, jdbc connections have been unsuccessful. mysql logs on May 11 simply show `[Note] Bad handshake`

I am following this post and can provide version and logs if it can help anyone. This is a very new issue. I haven't found any other recent references.

Answer (score 0):

There is another issue that has reported the same error as you did.

[AppScripts get a "Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password."](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187573928)

It seems to be actioned on, go there and star the issue so you get updates on it.